# Xcode Linking a framework to another framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linker-errors, xctest

I have an Xcode `Workspace` which builds a framework project

The `Framework1` project builds independently without any dependencies. And this framework is included to the `Workspace`

Another framework project `Framework2` uses `Framework1` as dependency and builds.

Now, If i run tests from `Framework2` project it gives below error

```
> 2017-06-23 15:44:17.029 xctest[1884:32036] The bundle
> “Framework2Tests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing
> necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle. 2017-06-23
> 15:44:17.029 xctest[1884:32036]
> (dlopen_preflight(/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linker-bhbtuyxcsiwybtheoopvbaexcyfr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Framework2Tests.xctest/Framework2Tests):
> Library not loaded: @rpath/Framwork1.framework/Framwork1   Referenced
> from:
> /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Linker-bhbtuyxcsiwybtheoopvbaexcyfr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Framework2.framework/Framework2
> Reason: image not found)
> Program ended with exit code: 82
```

Sample Project - https://github.com/nanjundas/LinkerError

Can any one help me here ??

[image: My Project Strucure]

[image: Linker]

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the test on simulator or device?

Currently, Xcode supports logic test and application test. if you are testing a framework and  have not chosen a Host Application in the General page of the test target, it will be a logic test(which means it will run itself without launch a host application).

I think you can try to add the framework1 in the link list of the Build Phases page of test target. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am testing it on simulator. And have only framework in my project as of now, Yes host application is empty - I should also add on App Target to test it ?

Comment: Because the Framework1 project also does not have any host app and i am able to test it successfully.

Comment: @nanjunda, if you are doing the logic test, I think the test target itself is an executable binary, so add the framework1 will help. You can check, I think the framework2 is already there for test target of framework2.

Comment: I linked Framework1 with "Framework2Tests". I still see the same error.

Comment: @nanjunda, I find the test executable will launch these frameworks through its rpath, can you have a try to add the path of framework1 into the Runpath Search Paths?(As the framework2 is a dependency and is already in the default rpath)

Comment: Yes have added the search paths and the project is building. It is able to build it without errors. I also tried giving a wrong path and it fails to build.